# PlasticSCM - Info required on storage space updation for deleted Repository

Tags: plasticscm

Good Day,

We recently deleted a repository which was using about 3.5GB storage, I can see the status of the repo as deleted, I want to know when would the storage space info get updated in the dashboard based on the deleted repo.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The storage use will be updated at the end of the month, when the invoice is generated.